# Calculating the availiability of things in a time range

Tags: php, math

the following situiation:
We have 3 things available at the same time.
The first is booked from 09:00 to 11:00.
The second is booked from 11:00 to 13:00
I want to calculate how much things are available from 10:00 to 12:00.
I've done it calculating how much things are booked in the range from 10:00 to 12:00.
It was 2. So the available things are 1.
But the first and the second could be the same. So the available things in the designated time are 2 and my calculation was wrong.

So I created the following algorithm to calculate the occupied things in a time range. the results came from a database query and contains the booking of things which are in my time range (result is an array and contains start,end and cnt which is the amount of booked things):

```
 $blocks = array();
    $times = array();
    foreach($results as $result){
     $block = array();
     $block['start'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",   $result['start'])->getTimestamp();
        $block['end'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $result['end'])->getTimestamp();
        $block['things'] = $result['cnt'];
        $blocks[] = $block;
        $times[] = $block['start'];
        $times[] = $block['end'];
    }

    $times = array_unique($times);
    $times = array_values($times);
    $peak = 0;

    foreach($times as $time){
        $timePeak = 0;
        foreach($blocks as $block){

            if($time >= $block['start'] && $time <= $block['end']){
                $timePeak += $block['things'];
            }
        }
        if($timePeak > $peak){
            $peak = $timePeak;
        }
    }

    return $peak;
}
```

[image: database]

whith this method, I am creating timestamps for every start and endtime of every booking in this range.
Then I have calculated the sum of all bookings of every timestamp. The maximum of the calculations (peak) was the maximum amount of bookings. So the available things are max - peak.

It works.
But is there a more elegant way to calculate it?

Comment: If you have this information in the database, the more elegant solution would be to simply write a database query.

Comment: It seemed to be the harder challenge. Do you want to give me a sample query? Its just a table with "start", "end", "cnt"

Comment: What's `cnt`? And how is the booking table linked to the table of available _"things"_? Update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: cnt is the amount per booking. For simplicity it could be 1. And the bookings are the things. so 1 booking is 1 thing. I've tried to describe it easier with things. my english is not the best :)

Comment: So with your current database structure you can't actually work out how many _things_ are available. You can only tell how many are unavailable... This suggests a flaw in your schema design.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the maximum availiable things are hardcored in this case. Its 3

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to this common coding interview problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/

If your "max things" is hardcoded then yeah I think you find the maximum booking of things during the given time and subtract from the max to get minimum availability over the range.  To do this, you need to consider all bookings that either start or end in your range.  As the efficient solution on that link suggests, you sort the starts and ends and then go through them to see your running utilization.

To handle the boundary case you talked about where a booking ending lines up with a booking start, make sure your sorting of "starts" and "ends" always sorts an "end" before a "start" when the time is the same so that you don't get the appearance of an overlap where one doesn't really exist.

I'm assuming you are working on a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And, you have data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `start`, `end`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-05-05 09:00:00', '2019-05-05 11:00:00'),
    (2, '2019-05-05 11:00:00', '2019-05-05 13:00:00'),
    (3, '2019-05-05 07:00:00', '2019-05-05 10:00:00'),
    (4, '2019-05-05 12:00:00', '2019-05-05 14:00:00'),
    (5, '2019-05-05 14:00:00', '2019-05-05 17:00:00'),
    (6, '2019-05-05 10:30:00', '2019-05-05 11:30:00');
```

This data has all the relevant cases you need to consider:

1. Bookings that end before your range
2. Bookings that start after your range
3. Bookings that intersect the start of your range
4. Bookings that intersect the end of your range
5. Bookings contained entirely within your range
6. Bookings that "hand-off" within your range

I looked at making a SQL query for this but stopped when it got more complicated than you would actually want to code in SQL. I think it's probably do-able but requires really ugly SQL. Definitely do this in code. I think the algorithm is to load all bookings relevant to your range with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings 
WHERE start BETWEEN :start AND :end
     OR end BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

That's all the bookings that will possibly matter. Then you sort the start and end events as distinct events as described earlier and loop over the list of events keeping a running counter going as well as a max value seen so far.  The running count will first go up and at the end it will go back down to zero, but may have multiple peaks in the middle.  So, you can't just stop the first time it goes down, you have to keep scanning until you get through all the events (or at least to your end time, but simpler and no real cost to just go all the way through the list).  Once done, you've got the maximum number of concurrent bookings.

I haven't tested or compiled this, so take it as psuedo-code.  I'd change your code to something like this:

```
//assumedly, prior to this point you have a
//$startTime and $endTime that you used to do the query mentioned above
//and the results of the query are in $results

$times = array();
foreach($results as $result){
    $time = array();
    $time['time'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",   $result['start'])->getTimestamp();
    $time['change'] = $result['cnt'];
    $times[] = $time;
    $time['time'] = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $result['end'])->getTimestamp();
    $time['change'] = -1 * $result['cnt'];
    $times[] = $time;
}

usort($times, function($lh, $rh) {
    if ($lh['time'] === $rh['time']) {
        return $lh['change'] - $rh['change']
    } else {
        return $lh['time'] < $rh['time'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

$maxPeak = 0;
$curVal = 0;
foreach($times as $time){
    //breaking early here isn't so much about optimization as it is about
    //dealing with the instantaneous overlap problem where something starts
    //right at the end time.  You don't want that to look like a utilization
    //that counts against you.
    if ($time['time'] === $endTime) {
        break;
    }

    $curVal += $time['change'];
    if ($curVal > $maxPeak) {
        $maxPeak = $curVal;
    }
}

//$maxPeak is the max number of things in use during the period
```

Comment: I've not used the between statements but the results are the same. I am not sure but I thinkt I've done the same you described here?

Comment: edit of my previous comment: I am not sure but I thinkt I've done the same you described here? Taking some markers and calculrating the maximum peak of them? I just thought this is a common problem and there would be an easier way to solve it.

Comment: @efge I think what you are doing is less efficient, though similar.  You are looking at all of your bookings at every "interesting" time (a time where something starts or stops), but this is O(N^2) (for N = bookings).  The algorithm I'm talking about (and is described on that link) is O(N) because it just goes through the list of relevant times, it doesn't have to look at all the bookings for each time.  The key piece missing is you need to track in your `times` array whether each time is a start or end and increment or decrement accordingly.

Comment: @efge Please let me know if this makes sense.  If it worked for you, please accept the answer so I get credit for it.  Thanks.